# get different url from document.getElementById .setAttribute href

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a select option with some values, example like this :

```js
function updateinput(e) {
var selectedOption = e.options[e.selectedIndex];
document.getElementById('data1').value = selectedOption.getAttribute('data1');
document.getElementById('data2').value = selectedOption.getAttribute('data2');
document.getElementById('data3').value = selectedOption.getAttribute('data3');
document.getElementById('data4').value = selectedOption.getAttribute('data4');
document.getElementById('data5').value = selectedOption.getAttribute('data5');
document.getElementById('data-url').setAttribute('href', 'http://google.com');  
document.getElementById('data-url').setAttribute('href', 'http://yahoo.com'); 
}
```

```html
<select>
<option data1='1.000.000' data2='0,-' data3='0,-' data4='0,-' data5='1.000.000' data-url='http://google.com'>30 Day</option>
<option data1='1.500.000' data2='500.000,-' data3='0,-' data4='0,-' data5='2.000.000' data-url='http://yahoo.com'>60 Day</option>
</select>


<input id="data1" name="data1" readonly type="text">
<input id="data2" name="data2" readonly type="text">
<input id="data3" name="data3" readonly type="text">
<input id="data4" name="data4" readonly type="text">
<input id="data5" name="data5" readonly type="text">
<a id="data-url" name="data-url">Anchor</a>
```

if I choose option **60** the url that is shown is the same: `http://google.com`

The one that should appear is `yahoo.com` but I'm confused about how to show or get a different url from same `document.getElementById` and `setAttribute`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could read the `url` value and then add the `href` attribute accordingly. I'm not sure if this is what you wanted. Have a look!

```js
function updateinput(e) {
 
   

 var selectedOption = e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex];
       var url = selectedOption.getAttribute('data-url');
var name = selectedOption.getAttribute('data-url-name');
    document.getElementById('data1').value = selectedOption.getAttribute('data1');
    document.getElementById('data2').value = selectedOption.getAttribute('data2');
    document.getElementById('data3').value = selectedOption.getAttribute('data3');
    document.getElementById('data4').value = selectedOption.getAttribute('data4');
    document.getElementById('data5').value = selectedOption.getAttribute('data5');
    document.getElementById('data-url').setAttribute('href', url);
      document.getElementById('data-url').innerHTML=name;
    }
```

```html
    <select onChange="updateinput(event)">
    <option data1='1.000.000' data2='0,-' data3='0,-' data4='0,-' data5='1.000.000' data-url='http://google.com' data-url-name='Google'>30 Day</option>
    <option data1='1.500.000' data2='500.000,-' data3='0,-' data4='0,-' data5='2.000.000' data-url='http://yahoo.com' data-url-name='Yahoo'>60 Day</option>
    </select>


    <input id="data1" name="data1" readonly type="text">
    <input id="data2" name="data2" readonly type="text">
    <input id="data3" name="data3" readonly type="text">
    <input id="data4" name="data4" readonly type="text">
    <input id="data5" name="data5" readonly type="text">
    <a id="data-url" name="data-url">Anchor</a>
```

Comment: Hi Sir @samuellawrentz, sorry ask again, how to change url http://google.com or http://yahoo into button or other name but still clickable (i mean like this change http://google.com to Google, text Google still click)

Comment: Hi @umild I have edited the answer. Please have a look and let me know if this is what you wanted.